# Are the columns retrieved before the paging?

Tags: sql-server

Why does such query

```
-- Select 20 columns here
SELECT COL1.. COL20
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE ...
ORDER BY COL1 DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

take **significantly** more execution time than

```
-- Select only 2 columns here
SELECT COL1, COL2
FROM [TABLE]
WHERE ...
ORDER BY COL1 DESC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
```

I am talking about a table with half a million records in it.

I would expect that the column content would be retrieved only for the paged records, which are just ten. And for 10 rows there should be no difference whether we select 2 or 20 columns.

But because I suffer a significant performance hit with the first query, to me it seems like the column content is retrieved before the paging?

Comment: Check the execution plan. Lots of stuff can matter for this. For example, the first query might be able to be completely served from an index, where the second might require going back to the table.

Comment: The most probable cause is in the second case there is an appropriate index that contains col1, col2, but does not contain all the 20 columns

Comment: I can only echo the index comment. It's the first thing that springs to mind. In a row-oriented storage environment you'll always fetch all data in your page, even if you only need 2 columns. If your index contains only those 2 columns, so will those pages. If you select more, you might end up still fetching all data. If you'd switch to a column-oriented storage, then your pages only contain single columns, which is nice for an OLAP environment, but terrible for an OLTP environment.

Comment: Ah, that must be it. The second query is served out of the index? Wow, could be. I didn't even know that's possible, SQL is not my strong side. What if I retrieve Col1, Col2 and Col3 (where Col3 is not in the index). Is it still better than retrieving Col1, Col2, Col3 and Col4, where Col4 is not in the index too, or once you go out of the index it's "all the same"?

Comment: As soon as you go outside of your index you'll see the loss because then your query will fetch some columns from it's index and the rest from pages containing all your columns. Fetching fewer columns will always be slightly more performant, but fetching 1 or 2 columns not sitting in your index won't be a noticeable difference.

Comment: But the original question is, why would SQL Server even bother fetching the content of these columns if they are not part of the returned set?

Comment: Because that's how your data is stored on your 8KB pages. SQL Server will fetch full pages to get the columns in the rows stored on those pages. This is the reason why columnstore indexes are created.